# Mirror image in OpenGl

Tags: android

I am new to OpenGl and needed some help.
I have a screen was able to draw a imageon it. Now i want to create a mirror image of the same image i.e i want the screen to be divided in 2 parts(horizontally) and then have the actual image at the bottom and create a duplicate image at the top just like a mirror image so that if a change is made to the bottom image it reflects on the top image too.

Please give suggestions. (I do not want canvas mirror image code)

Answer (score 0):

try this

sprite = BitmapFactory .decodeResource(appContext.getResources(),R.drawable.spritegfx);

Matrix temp1=new Matrix();

temp1.preScale(-1.0f,1.0f);

flipedSprite = Bitmap.createBitmap(sprite , 0, 0,sprite.getWidth(),sprite .getHeight(), temp1, false);

canvas.drawBitmap(flipedSprite , 0,0, null);

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i m not using canvas. I wanted answer in terms of OpenGL darw method.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm#tran0170